# OpenApi-Generator-Plugin - Is it possible to generate spring @Component Annotation in ApiClient when creating Webclients?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator

is it possible to generate my `XYZClient` and invoker `ApiClient` as Spring beans with an `@Component` Annotation ?

I am using the `open-api-generator` gradle plugin.

Answer (score 2):

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/324#issuecomment-785438335) about this in GitHub repo.
Still, AFIAK it is possible, there is an example in the discussion thread like this:

```
<configOptions>
      <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>@lombok.Builder @lombok.NoArgsConstructor @lombok.AllArgsConstructor</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
</configOptions>
```

It uses the lombok annotations, but it does not matter. You can specify a FQCN of spring `@Component` annotation or `@Service` annotation.

Comment: that does not help, because @Component/@Service annotation is needed on `*Api` classes, and not on model classes. There is no option like additionalApiTypeAnnotations to specify the annotation here